# Busca em uma lista com MobX e Get It

Tags: json, flutter, dart

**Estou tentando fazer meu sistema de busca funcionar**
O app é inteiro feito em Flutter, MobX pra estado e Get It para injeção e os dados vem de uma API json

Já tentei de algumas formas, mas não consigo fazer ele funcionar, mandei em alguns grupos e me disseram que meu código está correto, então não sabem o motivo de não funcionar

Esse é meu código:

Meus @observable

```
@observable
  String buscar = "";
```

Minha @action

```
 @action
  void setBuscando(String value) => buscar = value;
```

E meu @computed

```
  List get resultadoBusca {
    if (buscar.isEmpty) {
      return listaOSs;
    } else {
      return listaOSs.where((element) => element.contains(buscar)).toList();
    }
  }
```

E eu preciso exibir na minha lista, e aqui ta o código dela

```
      separatorBuilder: (_, index) => Divider(
        height: altura / 22,
      ),
      itemCount: dadosOS.tamanhoListaOSs, //limitador de objetos criados
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(
              context,
              "/detalhada",
              arguments: Detalhada(numero: index),
            );
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "O.S." + dadosOS.listaOSs[index]["id"].toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: largura / 30,
                      ),
                    ),
```

Meu campo de busca é em outra pag e ta assim

```
TextField(
                          autocorrect: false,
                          maxLines: 1,
                          onChanged: osLogin.setBuscando,
                          textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Nome, nº ou status",
                            hintText: "",
                            prefixIcon: Icon(
                              Icons.search,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Começamos adicionando depois do `.contains` isso `["project"]["name"]`, isso vai fazer que o vc escrever no campo de busca seja buscado no campo "nome" dentro do objeto "project" que tem em cada objeto da minha lista, da qual recebo da minha API

Então fica assim, com os nome substituídos:

```
@computed
  List get resultadoBusca {
    if (buscar.isEmpty) {
      return listaOSs;
    } else {
      return listaOSs
          .where((element) => element["project"]["name"]
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains(buscar.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    }
  }
```

Os `.toLowerCase()` tanto antes do `.contains` como dentro e após o `buscar` é para deixar tudo em letra minuscula para não ter diferenças nas buscas

Depois disso adicionei um `Observer(builder: (_) {});` na `ListView.separated`, para deixar a lista totalmente reativa (sem precisar tranformar em `StatefulWidget`)

Também alterei o contador da mesma para `dadosOS.resultadoBusca.length` (esse `dadosOS` é do Get It), alterei também o caminho em cada objeto que exibo dentro da ListView, então ao invés de de `dadosOS.listaOSs[index]["id"].toString()`, usei `dadosOS.resultadoBusca[index]["id"].toString()` em tudo que exibo na lista para só refletir o resultado da busca

**Próximos passos**

1. Conseguir passar o index da busca para minha pag de detalhes (já faço com o index da lista normal) [FEITO]
2. Conseguir adicionar operações em cascata no `return` da busca (pra fazer a busca em vários lugares da lista e não só em `["project"]["name"]`)

**Solução do 1.** Alterar tudo que antes tinha `listaOSs` para `resultadoBusca`, assim, por conta da condicional na busca, vai exibir o valor da lista de qualquer forma e ainda vai corresponder ao resultado da busca